# Does ULN2803A need an Optocoupler Isolation

Tags: relay, power-electronics, opto-isolator

When using ULN2803A, is it really needed to isolate the MCU side using an optocoupler like PCF817? Any disadvantages of not using the same?

I am making a relay driver using the same, powered by 5 V.

Comment: Are the MCU and the relays on the same PCB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not needed. Disadvantage: you have to power them with a PSU with same reference GND as MCU. Better alternative is to use a SMPS PSU with output voltage higher than MCU supply e.g 5V, then use LDO 3.3V to power MCU and 5V (from SMPS) to power ULN.